# ASP.NET MVC Custom View Path breaks Visual Studio shortcuts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, shortcut

I've seen a lot of articles on how to change the default paths for an ASP.NET MVC project so you can relocate or rename your Controllers, Models, and Views folders by extending the RazorViewEngine and specifying new path formats.

So far, this works great but the side-effect is that it has broken the Visual Studio shortcuts for "Go to View" or "Add View...".

Any ideas on whether those shortcut options can be customized to know about the new paths I've specified?

Thanks in advance! - Scott

Comment: yes, these can be customized. I just want to warn you that you will probably regret going down this path. The framework was designed the way it was for a reason.

Comment: Ok but do you care to elaborate how I could do it or why I would regret it?  MVC is designed to decouple and support multiple View Engines so all I'm doing is tailoring a view engine to look in different locations.  I don't have intent of blurring the separation of concerns at all.

Comment: Agreed. MVC is a very flexible pattern. ASP.NET MVC framework is a particular implementation of MVC. The advantages of using MS frameworks are the way the framework is tuned to work with Visual Studio. As you customize folder arrangements and locations of Contollers or Views, you lose some of the advantages you get from an IDE tuned to certain configuration. The war cry is Convention over Configuration.

Comment: Yep, I get that and thanks for the thoughts. Having said that, you mentioned that you could do it.  Do you know the approach? I'd like to see how deep the rabbit hole goes before I turn back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Visual Studio features cannot be extended to support custom paths. However, in the ASP.NET and Web Frameworks 2012.2 update that will soon be released (you can download a preview right now from [here](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/fall-2012-update)), the Add View functionality was updated to be a lot more flexible regarding which folders will have it enabled and which won't. It now supports Add View in any folder that is anywhere under a folder called "Views".

Regarding Go To View, that was not updated because unfortunately there is no way for the VS tooling to be aware of runtime customizations made to the view engine - I agree it would be cool, though!

(BTW my source for this information is that I work on ASP.NET MVC at Microsoft.)