# Visual Studio 2017: MVC Custom View Engine - Go To View not working

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, razorengine

We add some custom view locations to the Razor View Engine and this works well except for the small thing that Visual Studios "Go To View" no longer work.

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861714/asp-net-mvc-custom-view-path-breaks-visual-studio-shortcuts) but it is from 5 years ago and I wonder if some new settings have been added to Visual Studio 2017 for this? Or does any one know of an extension that can help?

Comment: Doubt it, but it's not a problem. Have been writing MVC websites since 2012, and never used "Go To View" - didn't know it existed until you asked about it.

Comment: I don't use it much either, but we are a big team and some might like to use it :)